# Docker multi-stage build not copying between stages

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to create a multi-stage build where the first stage does a yarn install for the theme and the second stage sets up the PHP environment for Drupal.

When I look at the output it looks like yarn install is being run but the `COPY` command near the bottom doesn't copy it across to the PHP image. If I'm right when this works the node_modules directory should be created on my local machine?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:cached
    env_file:
      - ./local-development.env
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file:
      - ./local-development.env
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as yarn-install
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./web/themes/material_admin_mine ./
RUN yarn install --verbose --force;

# from https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/drupal-8-php-requirements
FROM php:7.2-apache

# Install & setup Xdebug
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
&& echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_mode=req' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo 'xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Install git & mysql-client for running Drush
RUN apt update; \
apt install -y \
git \
mysql-client

# install the PHP extensions we need
RUN set -ex; \
\
if command -v a2enmod; then \
    a2enmod rewrite; \
fi; \
\
savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
\
apt-get update; \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    unzip \
    git \
; \
\
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer; \
\
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr; \
docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" \
    gd \
    opcache \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_pgsql \
    zip \
; \
\
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; \
ldd "$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"/*.so \
    | awk '/=>/ { print $3 }' \
    | sort -u \
    | xargs -r dpkg-query -S \
    | cut -d: -f1 \
    | sort -u \
    | xargs -rt apt-mark manual; \
\
apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN { \
    echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
    echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
    echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
    echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=60'; \
    echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
    echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini

# Various packages required to run Gulp in the theme directory
# gnupg is require for nodejs
RUN apt update; \
apt install gnupg -y; \
apt install gnupg1 -y; \
apt install gnupg2 -y; \
cd ~; \
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh; \
bash nodesource_setup.sh; \
apt install nodejs -y; \
npm install gulp-cli -g -y; \
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - ;\
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list; \
apt update && apt install yarn -y;

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=0 /app ./web/themes/material_admin_mine
```

Comment: `COPY` copies file from stage 0 to stage 1 (php image), not your host machine.

Comment: @Siyu Thanks but as there's a volume setup in the docker-compose shouldn't it sync those copied files to my local machine? Either way when I bash into the container it doesn't appear to have copied them their either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your Dockerfile ends with:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --from=0 /app ./web/themes/material_admin_mine
```

That should in fact copy the data from the first build stage to the final image.  But then when you launch the container with

```
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/html:cached
```

everything in the `/var/www/html` directory tree, including that final COPY step, is hidden and replaced with what's in the current directory on the host.  If you think of this like a copy, it's a one-way copy into the container; later changes will get copied back out to the host, but there's nothing that synchronizes what's in the image with what you previously had in the directory at startup time.

A Dockerfile intrinsically can't affect host filesystem content.  In your case it sounds like the host content is secondary to your application proper.  Given what's going into the first stage, I'd just run the `yarn install` step on the host and be done with it (you probably already have Node and Yarn available even).  Otherwise you'd need a more selective `volumes:` section that carefully tried to avoid overwriting that one directory; you might be able to mount something like `./web/src:/var/www/html/web/src` to only include your application code and avoid hiding the `.../web/themes` tree.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that explains what's happening and why my approach doesn't do what I am trying to achieve. My idea was to run all setup steps in the container build so a developer just builds the container and everything they need is setup for them automatically but it looks like that's not an easy, or potentially even correct, approach to take.